# Codeigniter loading a helper without the "_helper" suffix?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, helper, orientdb

I am trying to implement a OrientDB HTTP connection in Code Igniter, but I can't quite decide how to go about it.  Basically, I am using the php code found [here](https://github.com/doctrine/orientdb-odm), and I cannot decide whether to make that file collection into a library or a helper.

Right now, I am leaning towards a helper, because `$this->load->library()` automatically instantiates the class, where I will need the ability to call static methods as well (as can be seen in the use of `BindingParameters::create('http://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:2480/demo');`) in the example code.

So, if I make these files into helpers, which should not instantiate the classes, is there a way to load them without adding a "_helper" suffix to the files themselves?  I would like to avoid using require/include, but if there is no other way to accomplish this then I have no choice.

Does anyone have any tips or ideas that may help me with this?  Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Make it a library and pass any parameters to the class and its functions, creating a custom config file in application/config. I mean what is the problem about instantiating the class?

Comment: Well, it just never gets used as an instance, so it's a waste to instantiate it haha.

Comment: if you use a lot of core CI stuff then use a library . .

Comment: My way of doing this, put these stuffs in a sub-directory in helper directory create a helper & use require_once('subdir/filename.php');
then just load the helper so you can use $this->var = new filename('xx', 'yy');